# Does Drupal support persistent DB connections?

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, persistent, mysql-pconnect

Does Drupal support persistent DB connections?

If yes, how do you set them up and what are the downsides?

If no,... why not?

Comment: It might help to know what you'd ultimately like to accomplish with the persistent db connections. That might help point out an alternate solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Not anymore, in Drupal <= 5 yes but it wasn't excatly recommended as each Apache process could potentially grab a connection and hold it until the DB was spitting requests back with Max connection errors